# I made a git mistake, how can I recover my commits to push?

Tags: git, repository, rebase

I had two commits in my local copy that I wanted to merge before pushing so I did a

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

and there were two lines describing my previous commits. Now, instead of changing the second `pick` to `squash`, I mistakenly wiped both lines and replaced it with a single human readable commit message, wiping out the commit hashes too... and then I realized I made a mistake! 
I now get:

```
n$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 194db03
```

How can I repair this now? The two commits have disappeared from `git log` as well...

Comment: FWIW, don't panic about missing commits. See `git reflog`: commits are never "truly gone" unless GC'ed. Using a tool like Git Extensions can making 'missing commits' easier to visualize..

Answer (score 4):

Run `git rebase --abort` to cancel the rebase.

Comment: I would give you 10 up votes! Great, I feel like you saved my life! I'm new to git and am still finding my way around it! Tahnks sir!